# overflow-x hidden no funciona con responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Tengo esta pestaña creada en hasta arriba de mi página web, el overflow-x hidden aplicado en la versión web funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo aplico en el responsive no funciona.

He intentado con diferentes opciones que encontré en internet, pero ninguno me ha funcionado.

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo solucionarlo?

```
<div class="text-center">
<div class="row justify-content-end">
  <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 bg-info text-white py-2 container-top" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
      <span class="fw-bold text-top">¡NUESTROS PROCESOS DE RECLUTAMIENTO SON COMPLETAMENTE GRATUITOS!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Intenté con estas instrucciones, funciona pero la pestaña se vuelve fixed y se mueve cuando hacen scrolldown.

```
html{position:fixed;height:100%;overflow:hidden;}
body{margin:0;width:100vw;height:100%;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x: hidden;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
```